# DotNetOpenAuth functionality for .Net Core

Tags: .net-core, oauth

In my .Net Core coding i need to call a Web API that uses OAuth 2.0. For the .Net Framework i can use the DotNetOpenAuth library that supports OAuth 2.0 calls. This library is not available in .Net Core. Is there a library for .Net Core that supports OAuth 2.0 client access?

Answer (score 0):

There is already [AddOAuth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.oauthextensions.addoauth?view=aspnetcore-2.0) extension in .NET CORE.

Comment: AddOAuth is for Oauth 2.0 support for the web api's you create in your .net core coding. I am looking for a library to call an Oauth2 web api from .net core coding not for implementing an Oauth 2.0 web api.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/huysentruitw/oauth2-client-handler?